# Why does `df` indicate no available space when used is much less than total size, on my VPS?

Tags: hard-drive, vps, df

My VPS display this with `df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/simfs      100G   46G     0 100% /
```

Does anyone have a idea to fix this ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, contact your provider and tell him he has overcommitted his storage and he needs to fix it ASAP.

Explanation: With some type of VPS servers, you don't have a disk image with a fixed and guaranteed size. Instead, your file system is really just a subdirectory of a larger file system with a certain quota which is reported in your VPS as the disk size.

Problem is that if the provider overcommits storage and the real disk gets full, you end up with the problem you are facing now: The disk is reported as full even if you only used 50% of what the VPS reports as its size.

Comment: Does that really happen with some VPSes, or is it just with some kinds of containerisation?

Comment: @MadHatter: `simfs` is OpenVZ IIRC. I'll leave it to your own definition if you consider this a VPS or a container, but it certainly is marketed  as VPS. The way I understand it, I consider Docker et al as the next step of the concept behind OpenVZ.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Sven!  I'm fairly sure this is Yet Another Reason why I wish vendors would clarify that their "VPS" offerings are in fact containerised - it's **not** virtualisation, and people can get into trouble if they think they've got a super-cheap VPS when, in fact, they've just got a glorified `chroot` jail.

Comment: @MadHatter: I agree 100%.

Comment: Yes, this is OpenVZ. The directory on the host node where containers' files are stored has run out of space. (I'm also pretty sure this question is a dupe...)

Comment: @MichaelHampton [Here you go](http://serverfault.com/questions/714219/linux-says-my-space-is-full-with-2-4-50gb-used), you answered that one too!