# rdiff-backup bug or error? Disk quota exceeded but that is not true

Tags: backup, centos6, incremental-backup, rdiff-backup

I want to make a backup with rdiff-backup.

I have a backup VPS and I want to get the datas from remote host.

Here it is my command what I used:

```
rdiff-backup root@**RemoteIP**::/remotesourcefolder/ /targetlocalfolder/
```

After some seconds, they throw some error and stopped with this;

```
OSError: [Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded: '/demo/rdiff-backup.tmp.5'
[root@mn6 ~]# Fatal Error: Lost connection to the remote system
```

.

Before you write anything, I have a bounch of free space, and the source folder under 50 MB...

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/simfs      1.0T  137G  888G  14% /
none            512M  4.0K  512M   1% /dev
none            512M     0  512M   0% /dev/shm
```

What I'm doing wrong? *(Python version: 2.6.6, rdiff-backup: 1.2.8)*

Here is the full raw output: http://pastebin.com/raw/Bs4VRdwX

Answer (score 0):

OK, there is some space on the server (I'm assuming your "df -h" was executed on the backup server, not on the client) but maybe you have no free inode on the server (i.e. the maximum number of files has been reached on this FS). This is unlikely but you can check this with:

```
df -i
```

Else, have you checked your quotas on the server?

```
quota
```

An other reason could be that your rdiff-backup command, on the server side, is limited, especially if this server is shared with several users. It can be limited with the number of open files. Check this with:

```
ulimit -a
```

There may be other limitations you don't see on a shared platform (e.g. cgroup). But first try the above commands.

[edit] As a last resort, you should contact your provider. See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/714260/388397) (your provinder is using simfs too).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.


df -h was executed on the backup target server, where i execute the rdiff-backup line...



df -i -> http://pastebin.com/raw/LHczYdTS
quota -> http://pastebin.com/raw/R7FBChKX
ulimit -a -> http://pastebin.com/raw/BuqbEPbR

Comment: @moreasd Everything looks ok. You should contact your provider. See my edit.