# Ubuntu thinks disk is full, df says disk usage is at 100% but also says 132G/400G is in use

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, disk-space-utilization, df

Other applications are saying the disk is full as well, any ideas?

Here's the output from df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/simfs      400G  132G  714M 100% /
none            2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            410M  1.1M  409M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

Comment: Check your inode usage too: `df -iah`

Comment: Thanks Craig, I'll update my post with a link to this one. I somehow did not see that when searching

Comment: Answer is here, didn't see this when posting my question https://serverfault.com/questions/714219/linux-says-my-space-is-full-with-2-4-50gb-used

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is most likely that your OpenVZ host has a full disk.

The `/dev/simfs` device is used as a proxy filesystem, allowing the guest to isolate filesystems between guests while at the same time avoiding the overhead of allocating a block of space for an image-file disk.